MSYS2/UCRT64 - QTCreator no longer launches after recent package update
Recently, several packages updated on UCRT64. After this update, QTCreator no longer launches. Not even simple things like --help or --version produce any output. It instead seems to exit immediately:
/ >qtcreator --version
/ >qtcreator --help
/ >qtcreator
/ >

A restart of the system did not help.
Here's the list of what updated:
[2024-10-25T08:41:02-0600] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syyuu'
[2024-10-25T08:41:02-0600] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2024-10-25T08:41:17-0600] [PACMAN] starting core system upgrade
[2024-10-25T08:41:18-0600] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2024-10-25T08:44:23-0600] [ALPM] transaction started
[2024-10-25T08:44:23-0600] [ALPM] upgraded mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libltdl (2.4.7-2 -> 2.5.3-1)
[2024-10-25T08:44:27-0600] [ALPM] upgraded mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-petsc (3.22.0-1 -> 3.22.0-2)
[2024-10-25T08:44:34-0600] [ALPM] upgraded mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-qt6-base (6.7.2-2 -> 6.8.0-1)
[2024-10-25T08:44:34-0600] [ALPM] upgraded mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-qt6-5compat (6.7.2-1 -> 6.8.0-1)
[2024-10-25T08:44:40-0600] [ALPM] upgraded mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-qt6-declarative (6.7.2-1 -> 6.8.0-1)
[2024-10-25T08:44:40-0600] [ALPM] upgraded mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-qt6-shadertools (6.7.2-1 -> 6.8.0-1)
[2024-10-25T08:44:42-0600] [ALPM] upgraded mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-qt6-quick3d (6.7.2-1 -> 6.8.0-1)
[2024-10-25T08:44:42-0600] [ALPM] upgraded mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-qt6-serialport (6.7.2-1 -> 6.8.0-1)
[2024-10-25T08:44:42-0600] [ALPM] upgraded mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-qt6-svg (6.7.2-1 -> 6.8.0-1)
[2024-10-25T08:44:43-0600] [ALPM] upgraded mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-qt6-tools (6.7.2-1 -> 6.8.0-1)
[2024-10-25T08:44:43-0600] [ALPM] upgraded mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-qt6-translations (6.7.2-1 -> 6.8.0-1)
[2024-10-25T08:44:44-0600] [ALPM] upgraded mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-suitesparse (7.8.2-1 -> 7.8.3-1)
[2024-10-25T08:44:44-0600] [ALPM] transaction completed

Given that several QT-related packages updated, I'm assuming that's the cause.
In case it is a PATH related issue, here is my PATH:
/ucrt64/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /c/Windows/System32 /c/Windows /c/Windows/System32/Wbem /c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/ /usr/bin/site_perl /usr/bin/vendor_perl /usr/bin/core_perl

Is this a known issue? Should I expect a patch soon or do I need to do some kind of rollback?

Looks like the MSYS2 maintainers are aware and working to solve it: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/pull/22298

The fix is already available - update MSYS2 with: pacman -Suy

Fixed. Discussion here: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/pull/22298
commit: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/commit/14a9f46cf8b27cd98a58a005869245dd05682737
